# AWSTATS issue : all records dropped

Tags: records, awstats

I have a problem when using AWSTATS to analyse my apache logs.
In the past everything worked well.
But now the log format has changed for my server.

Old format example:

> 194.206.22.25 - - [14/Dec/2009:12:23:33 +0100] "GET /gPM-Systems/css/default.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1036

New format example:

> 356652,mics,194.206.22.24,194.206.22.24,-,[05/Jul/2011:15:11:18 +0200],"GET /index.html HTTP/x.x",302,-

For the old format the good LogFormat to choose was 4.
Now it is this custom format:

> LogFormat="%other %other %host %other %logname %time1 %methodurl
>   %code"

I also changed the LogSeparator to set "," instead of " ".

My problem is that all records are dropped.
-showdropped option shows that:

> Dropped record (method/protocol 'GET /apache_pb.gif' not qualified
>   when LogType=W):
>   356652,mics,194.206.22.24,194.206.22.24,-,[05/Jul/2011:15:11:18
>   +0200],"GET /apache_pb.gif HTTP/1.0",302,-

Comment: Thanks for the `-showdropped` option - I found out mine were dropped as they were skipped by `SkipHosts` and `SkipFiles` (D-oh!)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I changed the format of my logs. The format was changed, as well as using tab as the field separator, and this caused the same error.

For the `LogFile` configuration option, I was already using a pipe. So I switched the tab out for a space by adding `tr '\t' ' ' |` to the end. Then I modified the AWStats config to separate on spaces.

I was able to get AWStats to parse the logs after this. Perhaps it will work for you as well.

If you are not already using a pipe for the `LogFile` configuration option, you can use `cat` to get the files into `tr`.

```
LogFile="cat /log/file/path/*.log | tr '\t' ' ' |"
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace HTTP/1.x with nothing solve this issue